# Undefined is passed to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code for quiz app. The problem is, that somehow `undefined` is passed to the array `choices`.

```js
'use strict';

var quiz,
  actualQuestion = 1,
  getChoices,
  generateHtml,
  html = '',
  choices = [];

quiz = [{
  question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
  choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
  correctAnswer: 0
}, {
  question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom2?",
  choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
  correctAnswer: 0
}];

getChoices = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < quiz[actualQuestion].choices.length; i++) {
    choices[i] += quiz[actualQuestion].choices[i];
    console.log(choices[i]);
  }
}

generateHtml = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    html += '<label>' +
      '<input type="radio" name="answer">' +
      choices[i] +
      '</label>';
  }
}

getChoices();
generateHtml();

document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML = html;
console.log(
  html
);
```

```html
<form id="quiz">
  <div id="question">

  </div>
  <div id="answers">

  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Next">
</form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `choices[i] += quiz[actualQuestion].choices[i];`, the value of `choices[i]` is undefined since you are defining an empty array so you have `choices[i] = undefined + quiz[actualQuestion].choices[i];`

Just change it to `choices[i] = quiz[actualQuestion].choices[i];`

```js
'use strict';

var quiz,
  actualQuestion = 1,
  getChoices,
  generateHtml,
  html = '',
  choices = [];

quiz = [{
  question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
  choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
  correctAnswer: 0
}, {
  question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom2?",
  choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
  correctAnswer: 0
}];

getChoices = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < quiz[actualQuestion].choices.length; i++) {
    choices[i] = quiz[actualQuestion].choices[i];
    console.log(choices[i]);
  }
}

generateHtml = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    html += '<label>' +
      '<input type="radio" name="answer">' +
      choices[i] +
      '</label>';
  }
}

getChoices();
generateHtml();

document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML = html;
console.log(
  html
);
```

```html
<form id="quiz">
  <div id="question">

  </div>
  <div id="answers">

  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Next">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are concatenating undefined with a string which is why undefined appears as an option:

`choices[i] += quiz[actualQuestion].choices[i];`

Ex.: `choices[0]` is undefined since `choices = [];` Thus, it will get concatenated with `quiz[actualQuestion].choices[i]` which will result in the string "undefined" being concatenated with "David Cameron".

Answer (score 1):

Because, when you declare the `choices` array there are no elements. So, when you use `choices[i]` for the first time, it is `undefined`.

To solve this problem, initialize the array element to empty string if it is `undefined` using following statement.

```
choices[i] = choices[i] ? choices[i] : '';
```

**Demo**

```js
'use strict';

var quiz,
  actualQuestion = 1,
  getChoices,
  generateHtml,
  html = '',
  choices = [];

quiz = [{
  question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
  choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
  correctAnswer: 0
}, {
  question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom2?",
  choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
  correctAnswer: 0
}];

getChoices = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < quiz[actualQuestion].choices.length; i++) {
    choices[i] = choices[i] ? choices[i] : '';
    choices[i] += quiz[actualQuestion].choices[i];
    console.log(choices[i]);
  }
}

generateHtml = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    html += '<label>' +
      '<input type="radio" name="answer">' +
      choices[i] +
      '</label>';
  }
}

getChoices();
generateHtml();

document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML = html;
console.log(
  html
);
```

```html
<form id="quiz">
  <div id="question">

  </div>
  <div id="answers">

  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Next">
</form>
```